# Link was changing by itself while opening in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i was trying to scrape a `bikedekho.com` using selenium python.
And the main thing is I have to scrape that page by using the engine capacity filter(cc) one by one.
So when I applied filters in browser it applies perfectly by changing the link.

- But when I tried to open this particular filter by copying and pasting this link, it changes automatically.
  i don't know why and how;

i tried using the selenium driver python

```
driver.get('https://www.bikedekho.com/used-bikes+125cc-150cc+in+ahmedabad')
```

when i tried to open this

it opens the page with link :
`https://www.bikedekho.com/used-cars+145cc-165cc+in+ahmedabad`

I just want to open that previous link perfectly.

Comment: The same thing happens when you paste that link into a regular browser. It's just the way that website works, it doesn't have every possible combination.

Comment: So if you search for something that doesn't exist, it redirects to a close match.

Comment: But it exist. whenever i tried to apply the filter(125cc-150cc) from the page it shows the perfect link and doesn't redirect to changed link. Just go through the site and try to apply the filter, then check the link.

Comment: Why don't you just apply filters (125cc - 150cc) via selenium rather than opening the hyperlink with filters directly. Clearly website is not liking the filtered URL, that's how the website is designed to work perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in chrome's inspect option under network tab the status code.
You can see the status code as 301. They are redirecting to 145-165cc. You can get the same thing by getting the xpath of element.
Here is example, how you can do it.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.bikedekho.com/used-bikes+in+ahmedabad"

driver.get(url)
driver.set_window_position(0,0)
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//label[@title='150 - 200 cc']/..").click()
input()
```

[Network tab screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPM58.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No matter what link you end up to, use Selenium to find element 125 - 150 cc in ENGINE DISPLACEMENT, click it and that's it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I took your code, opened in ***maximized*** mode and executed the program and it seems works perfecto as follows:

- Code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get("https://www.bikedekho.com/used-bikes+125cc-150cc+in+ahmedabad")
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: bikedekho]

Comment: But i don't want site with 145cc-165cc. I want the site to open with link 125cc-150cc